# 'Promise' is undefined error when run on IE

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller

I have a controller code that runs fine on Chrome, but when run on IE 10 the same code returns

```
ReferenceError: 'Promise' is undefined
```

The function that returns the error is:

```
new Promise(function(resolve) {
    MetaModel.load($scope, (regionExist ? reqParmRegion[1] : reqParmRegion), (screenExist ? reqParmScreen[1] : reqParmScreen), resolve);
}).then(function(){

    loadRelationshipByStep($scope.preStep);
     if($rootScope.regionId === 'us') {
        $rootScope.currRel = 'itself';
    } 

    if($rootScope.screenId.indexOf('search') !== -1 ){
       EnumerationService.loadEnumerationByTab();
    }  
    // load data for tab click
    if($rootScope.currRel !== 'undefined' && $rootScope.currRel !== 'itself' && $scope.regionId !== 'us'){
        $scope.loadDataByTab($rootScope.currRel);
    } else if($rootScope.resourceHref !== undefined) {
        var params = {};
         resourceFactory.get($rootScope.resourceHref, params, $rootScope.headers).success(function(responseData){
            var data = responseData.data || responseData;
            if (data) {
                $scope.data=data;
                EnumerationService.executeEnumerationFromBackEnd(data, 'create');
                if($rootScope.regionId === 'us'){
                    EnumerationService.executeEnumerationFromBackEnd(data, 'fetch');    
                }
            }
        });            
    }
});
```

Do i need to add any $promise variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE does not support native the native javascript `Promise`. See [browser compatibility on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Browser_compatibility).

Angular includes the [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service that provides promise functionality. You can create a deferred object using `$q.defer()` and return the promise from that object.

I think that the equivalent code would be:

```
// create the deferred object
var deferred = $q.defer();

// pass the resolve method as the callback
MetaModel.load($scope, (regionExist ? reqParmRegion[1] : reqParmRegion), 
    (screenExist ? reqParmScreen[1] : reqParmScreen), deferred.resolve);

// chain actions onto the promise.
deferred.promise.then(function(){

    loadRelationshipByStep($scope.preStep);
     if($rootScope.regionId === 'us') {
        $rootScope.currRel = 'itself';
    } 

    if($rootScope.screenId.indexOf('search') !== -1 ){
       EnumerationService.loadEnumerationByTab();
    }  
    // load data for tab click
    if($rootScope.currRel !== 'undefined' && $rootScope.currRel !== 'itself' && $scope.regionId !== 'us'){
        $scope.loadDataByTab($rootScope.currRel);
    } else if($rootScope.resourceHref !== undefined) {
        var params = {};
         resourceFactory.get($rootScope.resourceHref, params, $rootScope.headers).success(function(responseData){
            var data = responseData.data || responseData;
            if (data) {
                $scope.data=data;
                EnumerationService.executeEnumerationFromBackEnd(data, 'create');
                if($rootScope.regionId === 'us'){
                    EnumerationService.executeEnumerationFromBackEnd(data, 'fetch');    
                }
            }
        });            
    }
});
```

Comment: Although I used your solution to fix the issue temporarily, the permanent solution for all the ES6 issues seems to be using a ES6-Shim. I used the Shim mentioned here: https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim

Comment: @RahulVarma, I don't know is you are using Protractor for testing, but if you are I don't know how it integrates with native (ES6-Shim) promises. When using `$q` Protractor is aware of unresolved promises and will wait for them to complete. If you are using Protractor it would be interesting to know of any differences between the two options.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promiseCorrect me if I'm wrong, but it seems to me that you're using the native implementation of [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which is not supported by IE (yet).

In this case, try using a [polyfill](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise).

Also, you may use [Angular's $q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), which is a Promisse Pattern implementation based on [kriskowal's Q module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q).

Example:

```
$q(function (resolve, reject) {
    MetaModel.load($scope, (regionExist ? reqParmRegion[1] : reqParmRegion), (screenExist ? reqParmScreen[1] : reqParmScreen), resolve);
}).then(function () {

    loadRelationshipByStep($scope.preStep);
     if($rootScope.regionId === 'us') {
        $rootScope.currRel = 'itself';
    } 

    if($rootScope.screenId.indexOf('search') !== -1 ){
       EnumerationService.loadEnumerationByTab();
    }  
    // load data for tab click
    if($rootScope.currRel !== 'undefined' && $rootScope.currRel !== 'itself' && $scope.regionId !== 'us'){
        $scope.loadDataByTab($rootScope.currRel);
    } else if($rootScope.resourceHref !== undefined) {
        var params = {};
         resourceFactory.get($rootScope.resourceHref, params, $rootScope.headers).success(function(responseData){
            var data = responseData.data || responseData;
            if (data) {
                $scope.data=data;
                EnumerationService.executeEnumerationFromBackEnd(data, 'create');
                if($rootScope.regionId === 'us'){
                    EnumerationService.executeEnumerationFromBackEnd(data, 'fetch');    
                }
            }
        });            
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Native [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is an ES6 feature which is not supported by old browsers. You need to add a polyfill to support old browsers, for example https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill.

Since you're using AngularJS you can use the [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service instead to create promises which work cross browsser.