# promise not define in IE11 in angular 9 app

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

I Just created an angular 9 app and it does not load in IE11.
I have added all the polyfills required including the  "core-js/es/promise" for polyfilling promise.
But still IE11 is complaining about "promise not defined".
why angular team still have not added that polyfill in their polyfill file?
We are transpiling our code in es5.
I looked at the internet and got the old answers which are not applicable currently.
I can not include any cdn link in my index.html file as per corporate policy.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you checking dev build or prod build of angular in IE11 ?

Comment: both and it is not working on both.

Comment: How can we know if you're missing anything if we don't know what you have? Show your configuration files, share how you're building and deploying, share the exact error message, etc.

Comment: What is exactly the error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Promise' is undefined error when run on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069665/promise-is-undefined-error-when-run-on-ie)

Comment: guys, as I can not post any code from my office laptop, so let me create it on my personal laptop and I can share the snap and configs as well.

Comment: You could try to add the [promise-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-polyfill). It's a lightweight ES6 promise polyfill for IE or any other browser that does not support native promises. If the issue still exists, please provide [a minimal code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can reproduce the issue so that we can have a test in IE. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

In your **polyfills.ts** uncomment the following imports.
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/

```
 import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
 import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

If it not works than do the following.
change compiler output to ES5 in the tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5"
  }
}
```